# Magento new product widget overlap image and title

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

I use the new product widget in mangento 1.9.
but the title is overlap on image.
I don't know why.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue. Does it happen when you switch to `default/default` native theme and disable custom extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fully recreate the issue you are having. From what you are showing in the picture, I can see two things for sure. You are using the `default` package and the `modern` theme for your site. You also have some custom styles in there that are changing around the layout and sizing of the products in small ways outside of the default styling. When I tried to replicate this, i got this result:

[image]

To get this, I just positioned the images of the product absolutely, as seen here:

[image]

So my guess is that you have some rouge styles on the page that is causing this overlap. Look at the image I posted and find the elements on the page that are not working right, and get back to us with that info. From there we can figure the right solution.